# How to pick fractional seconds in date pattern of spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, date, apache-spark-sql

I'm working in spark SQL and using this function to_date to convert the timestamp string in date format. But I'm unable to pick fractional seconds even though the documentation suggests so. [Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) it suggests that we can 'S' continuously, upto 6 singificant places, for fraction patterns.

For instance:

```
to_date("2017-09-09T21:01:12Z","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") -> working and returns date
to_date("2017-09-09T21:01:12.234433Z","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'") -> result in null
```

Can anybody suggests the possible reason for this behavior?

Edit (19-Apr-2023) : I believe this might be due to the version of spark that I'm using. Its not an offcial spark version and is probably a distribution of cloudera(I will confirm this) because the exact same function is properly working in official spark version 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Two things should be changed ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)):

1. the format string is case-sensitive and
2. the character to use for the zone-offset with offset zero printed as `Z` is `X`

So the two format strings should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX` and `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX`, but using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'` also works of the zone-offset is always zero.

Comment: I was using the same pattern but wrote differently. I've now edited my question. It doesn't work for fractional seconds. I have tried yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX as well but in vain.

Comment: Is it specifically related to any spark version? Just in case I'm using 2.4.7.7.1.7.48-2 as spark-core,spark-sql etc

Comment: Your version number 2.4.7.... suggests that you are not using an "official" Spark version from spark.apache.org but a custom version, maybe from Cloudera. Maybe you could try to open a support ticket at Cloudera?

Comment: Understood, Will dig in a bit more and most probably will raise a support ticket. Appreciate your help werner